# Update Where Sql table

Tags: c#, sql

How do I introduce "Where" to this SQL query? What I want is to modify a table for specified primary key(StudentID)

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update StudentReg Set FirstName='" + txtfirstname.Text + "', LastName='" + txtlastname.Text + "', Class='" + txtclass.Text + "', [Password]='" + txtpassword.Text + "'", conn);
```

Comment: Greetings from [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) ;-)

Comment: firstly: **USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES!** or enjoy all your data being leaked. secondly: **never never never never EVER** store passwords as plain text - or enjoy all your passwords being leaked as plain text and every single one of your users suing you.

Comment: Thanks Franz...I am a student, so thanks for the good lessons from veterans like you :) . This is not an actual application, but I really appreciate the lessons.

Answer (score 2):

Please when you want to execute some sql command use parameterized query.
For example:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Update StudentReg
                                   Set FirstName = @firstName,
                                       LastName  = @lastName,
                                       Class     = @class,
                                       Password  = @password
                                   where 
                                     Id = @id", conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", (int)txtId.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtfirstname.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtlastname.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", txtclass.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text.Trim());

int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Why parametrized query, because you want to avoid sql injection.
Read here: [Parametrized queries](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx)

Edit:
I late with my answer :D, as @Isaí Hinojos wrote on his answer you can use on  this approach in his example:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Jack";
```

where you specify which type is data in table, second parameter in method AddWithValue.

Comment: **[AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)**

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use parameters, and to answer your question:

```
var query = "UPDATE StudentReg Set FirstName=@first, LastName = @last, Class = @class, [Password] = @pass WHERE StudentID = @id"; 

var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Jack";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "0101D54";
//same for the rest  of the parameters
```